Unable to solve an integration
I would like to solve the following integration:
denom=44.3705 - 17.0692 Pe + 17.0692 Pp - 38.3886 Pe Pp + 35.6879 x -
13.1912 Pe x + 13.1912 Pp x - 43.2119 Pe Pp x + 22.5263 x^2 -
6.59222 Pe x^2 + 6.59222 Pp x^2 - 11.6631 Pe Pp x^2;
Integrate[(1+x+x^2)/denom,{x,xmin,xmax},Assumptions -> {Element[xmin, Reals], Element[xmax, Reals],
Element[Pe, Reals], Element[Pp, Reals]}].
It has been two hours, and there is no output. The mathematical is still running. Could anyone provide a solution?

For me, this returned a result instantly (maybe you have weird things defined that were not cleared out - clear everything from your session and try again. Integrate[((1 + x + x^2)/(44.3705 - 17.0692 a + 17.0692 b -
38.3886 a b + 35.6879 x - 13.1912 a x + 13.1912 b x -
43.2119 a b x + 22.5263 x^2 - 6.59222 a x^2 + 6.59222 b x^2 -
11.6631 a  b  x^2)), x]

Mathematica checks wether zeros  denom==0 are located inside the integration range xmin,xmax. Perhaps you have additional information concerning Pe,Pp,xmin,xmax?

@Moo, Thank you so much. It worked. When I set the limit while performing the integration, it takes time. But, after performing the integration, wrt x and then put the limit. Then it works fine.

The GenerateConditions->False option helps in 14.0 on Windows 10:
denom = 44.3705 - 17.0692  Pe + 17.0692  Pp - 38.3886  Pe  Pp + 
35.6879  x - 13.1912  Pe  x + 13.1912  Pp  x - 
43.2119  Pe  Pp  x + 22.5263  x^2 - 6.59222  Pe  x^2 + 
6.59222  Pp  x^2 - 11.6631  Pe  Pp  x^2;
Integrate[(1 + x + x^2)/denom, {x, xmin, xmax}, 
Assumptions -> {Element[xmin, Reals], Element[xmax, Reals], 
Element[Pe, Reals], Element[Pp, Reals]},  GenerateConditions -> False]


-((0.0857405 ((3.78178 +2.5796 Pp+0.375545 Pp^2+Pe^2 (0.375545 -0.768755 Pp-5.43917 Pp^2)+Pe (-2.5796-0.89038 Pp+0.768755 Pp^2)) ArcTan[(3.0599 +Pe (-1.13102+Pp (-3.70501-2. xmax)-1.13044 xmax)+3.86283 xmax+Pp (1.13102 +1.13044 xmax))/(\[Sqrt](20.0281 +12.9862 Pp+2.02964 Pp^2+Pe (-12.9862-22.0315 Pp-4.9148 Pp^2)+Pe^2 (2.02964 +4.9148 Pp-0.561267 Pp^2)))]+(-3.78178-2.5796 Pp-0.375545 Pp^2+Pe (2.5796 +0.89038 Pp-0.768755 Pp^2)+Pe^2 (-0.375545+0.768755 Pp+5.43917 Pp^2)) ArcTan[(3.0599 +Pe (-1.13102+Pp (-3.70501-2. xmin)-1.13044 xmin)+3.86283 xmin+Pp (1.13102 +1.13044 xmin))/(\[Sqrt](20.0281 +12.9862 Pp+2.02964 Pp^2+Pe (-12.9862-22.0315 Pp-4.9148 Pp^2)+Pe^2 (2.02964 +4.9148 Pp-0.561267 Pp^2)))]+\[Sqrt](20.0281 +12.9862 Pp+2.02964 Pp^2+Pe (-12.9862-22.0315 Pp-4.9148 Pp^2)+Pe^2 (2.02964 +4.9148 Pp-0.561267 Pp^2)) (-1.93142 xmax+0.56522 Pe xmax-0.56522 Pp xmax+1. Pe Pp xmax+1.93142 xmin-0.56522 Pe xmin+0.56522 Pp xmin-1. Pe Pp xmin+(0.564241 +Pe (-0.2829-1.3525 Pp)+0.2829 Pp) Log[3.80435 +3.0599 xmax+1.93142 xmax^2+Pp (1.46352 +1.13102 xmax+0.56522 xmax^2)+Pe (-1.46352-1.13102 xmax-0.56522 xmax^2+Pp (-3.29146-3.70501 xmax-1. xmax^2))]+(-0.564241-0.2829 Pp+Pe (0.2829 +1.3525 Pp)) Log[3.80435 +3.0599 xmin+1.93142 xmin^2+Pp (1.46352 +1.13102 xmin+0.56522 xmin^2)+Pe (-1.46352-1.13102 xmin-0.56522 xmin^2+Pp (-3.29146-3.70501 xmin-1. xmin^2))])))/((-1.93142-0.56522 Pp+Pe (0.56522 +1. Pp))^2 \[Sqrt](20.0281 +12.9862 Pp+2.02964 Pp^2+Pe (-12.9862-22.0315 Pp-4.9148 Pp^2)+Pe^2 (2.02964 +4.9148 Pp-0.561267 Pp^2))))


$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

Using exact values
denom = 44.3705 - 17.0692   Pe + 17.0692   Pp - 38.3886   Pe   Pp + 
     35.6879   x - 13.1912   Pe   x + 13.1912   Pp   x - 
     43.2119   Pe   Pp   x + 22.5263   x^2 - 6.59222   Pe   x^2 + 
     6.59222   Pp   x^2 - 11.6631   Pe   Pp   x^2 // 
  Rationalize // Simplify;

(int = Assuming[
    {xmax > xmin, Element[{Pe, Pp, xmin, xmax}, Reals]},
    Integrate[(1 + x + x^2)/denom, {x, xmin, xmax},
      GenerateConditions -> False] // FullSimplify]) // AbsoluteTiming

(* {23.8313, (5000 (2 Sqrt[
       5] (-1286070350700 - Pp (877244242835 + 127711623038 Pp) + 
         Pe (877244242835 + 11 (27526494366 - 23766389165 Pp) Pp) + 
         Pe^2 (-127711623038 + 
            1705 Pp (153331543 + 1084866910 Pp))) ArcTanh[(-659222 Pp xmax - 
           5 (356879 + 131912 Pp + 450526 xmax) + 
           Pe (659560 + 659222 xmax + 5 Pp (432119 + 233262 xmax)))/(Sqrt[
           5] √(-1362193285095 - 4 Pp (220811452115 + 34510991132 Pp) + 
              Pe^2 (-138043964528 + Pp (-334274951144 + 38173989485 Pp)) + 
              2 Pe (441622904230 + Pp (749223680253 + 167137475572 Pp))))] + 
      2 Sqrt[5] (1286070350700 + Pp (877244242835 + 127711623038 Pp) + 
         Pe^2 (127711623038 - 1705 Pp (153331543 + 1084866910 Pp)) + 
         Pe (-877244242835 + 
            11 Pp (-27526494366 + 
               23766389165 Pp))) ArcTanh[(-659222 Pp xmin - 
           5 (356879 + 131912 Pp + 450526 xmin) + 
           Pe (659560 + 659222 xmin + 5 Pp (432119 + 233262 xmin)))/(Sqrt[
           5] √(-1362193285095 - 4 Pp (220811452115 + 34510991132 Pp) + 
              Pe^2 (-138043964528 + Pp (-334274951144 + 38173989485 Pp)) + 
              2 Pe (441622904230 + Pp (749223680253 + 167137475572 Pp))))] - 
      5 √(-1362193285095 - 4 Pp (220811452115 + 34510991132 Pp) + 
          Pe^2 (-138043964528 + Pp (-334274951144 + 38173989485 Pp)) + 
          2 Pe (441622904230 + 
             Pp (749223680253 + 167137475572 Pp))) (2 (-1126315 + 329611 Pe - 
            329611 Pp + 583155 Pe Pp) (xmax - xmin) + (658080 - 329949 Pe + 
            329949 Pp - 1577440 Pe Pp) Log[
           2218525 + 853460 Pp + 5 xmax (356879 + 225263 xmax) + 
            Pp xmax (659560 + 329611 xmax) - 
            Pe (853460 + xmax (659560 + 329611 xmax) + 
               5 Pp (383886 + xmax (432119 + 116631 xmax)))] + (-658080 + 
            329949 Pe - 329949 Pp + 1577440 Pe Pp) Log[
           2218525 + 853460 Pp + 5 xmin (356879 + 225263 xmin) + 
            Pp xmin (659560 + 329611 xmin) - 
            Pe (853460 + xmin (659560 + 329611 xmin) + 
               5 Pp (383886 + xmin (432119 + 116631 xmin)))])))/((1126315 + 
      329611 Pp - 
      Pe (329611 + 583155 Pp))^2 √(-1362193285095 - 
       4 Pp (220811452115 + 34510991132 Pp) + 
       Pe^2 (-138043964528 + Pp (-334274951144 + 38173989485 Pp)) + 
       2 Pe (441622904230 + Pp (749223680253 + 167137475572 Pp))))} *)


As the denominator is just a second degree polynomial you could just simplify integral and back substitute coefficients (care re: zeros denominator) and then proceeding as per other answers. I will not display the substituted answer but the form of answer:
denom = 44.3705 - 17.0692    Pe + 17.0692    Pp - 
   38.3886    Pe    Pp + 35.6879    x - 13.1912    Pe    x + 
   13.1912    Pp    x - 43.2119    Pe    Pp    x + 22.5263    x^2 - 
   6.59222    Pe    x^2 + 6.59222    Pp    x^2 - 
   11.6631    Pe    Pp    x^2; 

Then
r = CoefficientRules[denom, x] /. {{0} -> a, {1} -> b, {2} -> c}
i = Integrate[(1 + x + x^2)/(a + b  x + c  x^2), {x, xmin, xmax}, 
  Assumptions -> {max > min, a \[Element] Reals, b \[Element] Reals, 
    c \[Element] Reals}, GenerateConditions -> False]


then just use i/.r.
